# WKWebView disappears when I try to move it into another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView. At some point I create a new UIView and want to move that WKWebView from the former view into the newly created UIView.
But when I do that - the WKWebView gets disappeared.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[webView removeFromSuperview];
[myView addSubview:webView];
```

So the webView should appear in `myView`, right?
But it gets disappeared somehow.
Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

**UPDATE**
My updated code is:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
webView.frame = myView.frame;

[webView removeFromSuperview];
[myView addSubview:webView];

[self.view addSubView:myView];
```

Still it's disappearing

Comment: check if webView is nil after removal, also you are adding it to a UIView but you are not setting his frame

Comment: If you set the frame of webview with the frame of myview, you may offset the webview outside myview . Set webview origin to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting webView frame = to `myView` frame, also you need to add `myView` to a superView to be visible, `myView` is not in any hierarchy as far as your code shows

Comment: I've updated my question code. Basically I do what you just mentioned but it disappears

Comment: I even added background color to `myView` and now I see `myView` but no webView in it even when I check with hierarchy window

Comment: @JohnDoe put a print after removing webView from original superView to see if is deallocate or not, and which is the frame values?

Comment: @JohnDoe something like `NSLog(webView)` after `[webView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: So after removal of webView:
`(origin = (x = 45, y = 268.66666666666669), size = (width = 400, height = 400))` and `myView` the exact same.
After adding webView as a subView the same frame is kept

Comment: I mean print the webView after removal, only to see if is being deallocated

Comment: @JohnDoe this webView is originally added as an outlet?